# Installation errors with tensorflow 2.1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

1. `pip3 --version` == `pip 20.0.2 from /home/nitin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`
2. `python --version` == `python 3.7.6`

i created an environment with `conda create --name tensorflow`. I had tensorflow 2.0 installed in it with which, i did with conda. I upgraded it with `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` from inside the tensorflow environment

Now, when i do `import tensorflow as tf` i get the following error

`2020-01-28 23:01:06.791110: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-01-28 23:01:06.791210: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-01-28 23:01:06.791226: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.`

I dont seem to understand what went wrong. Any help?

Comment: These are all warnings indicating you don't have the needed libraries for Nvidia GPU support in TF. If you don't need it - you can safely ignore those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python 3.7 CPU then upgrade it like: pip install --upgrade     https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl

Answer (score 2):

This is just warning from tensorflow stating that if you want to improve latency and throughput of some models you can harness the power of tensorRT. However you cannot use it because libnvinfer is not installed.
In order to install it,

```
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1604_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1604_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libnvinfer6=6.0.1-1+cuda10.1 \
    libnvinfer-dev=6.0.1-1+cuda10.1 \
    libnvinfer-plugin6=6.0.1-1+cuda10.1
```

This is with reference to the installation instructions provided by [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)